# LibreOffice Calc Didn't Read Data with a formula (Error?)

Tags: libreoffice, data, spreadsheet, graph

So I have a data like this :

```
(First Number) (=RIGHT(A1, 3))
19132 132
56112 112
```

So, the second column formula is =RIGHT(A1,3) and so on. When I created the graph, it's show zero data, there are no data  in the graph.

But when I tried change the second column with data (not a formula), the graph can read the data now...

Why doesn't my LibreOffice Calc read any data if I put formula into the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LO Calc can't create a chart based on the column `B`'s values because they are **text strings instead of numerical values**. This is because **[RIGHT()](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#RIGHT)** is a [text function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions), trying to read the input as string and returning a string. The solution is just to apply to [**VALUE()** function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#VALUE) to the output of the RIGHT() function, so that the result of the complete formula is an integer:

> `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,3))`

You can check the type of a cell's content using one of the [information functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions). The [**TYPE()** function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#TYPE) returns an integer indicating the type, the **[ISTEXT()](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#ISTEXT)** and [**ISNUMBER()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#ISNUMBER) functions return `true` or `false`.

An easier way would be to use the [**MOD()** function](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Mathematical_Functions#MOD):

> `=MOD(A1, 1000)`

returns the remainder of `A1` divided by 1000, so it effectively strips the part of the number > 999. With `A1` = 314972, `MOD(A1, 1000)` will return 972. This way, you could get rid of the type conversion `number -> string -> number`.

Here's an overview of the different solutions:

[image]